# Changes the default database owner in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I change the default database owner when creating a new database in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::MyDB TO sa;
```

Note, this doesn't add the new owner to db_owner (sa + sysadmin map to dbo user which is different)